# ArcGIS JavaScript query task not returning feature

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, query

I am using query task to do a attribute query for features with a where clause. I have verified that the specific layer I am querying has the field `LK_ID_NUM`.

My query task do not return an error, but no features are found. Therefore the results.features returns undefined. I checked the where condition (`LK_ID_NUM = 46014`) directly on the ArcGIS Rest service and the query returns a feature successfully. I tried the query without the where clause, and it still did not return any features, only the feature layer information is returned.

I Thought the issue is that i require a geometry input to the query. I tried added a extent geometry and changed the spatial relationship to "Contains". But this did not solve the issue. There is still no features returned.

My JS query code is shown below.

```
                    task.featureLayer = layer;
                    task.queryTask = new QueryTask( this.validateUrlToken.addTokenIfApplicable( layerUrl ) );
                    task.query = new Query();
                    task.query.outFields = [
                        "*"
                    ];
                    task.query.returnGeometry = true;
                    task.query.outSpatialReference = this.map.map.spatialReference;         
                    var whereclause = "LK_ID_NUM = " + gislink  ;
                    task.query.where = whereclause;    //only query features that has same LinkID
                    console.log("query condition: ", whereclause);
                    tasks.push( task );
                    console.log("Query Tasks captured: ",task);
                    

                    var defferedTask = task.queryTask.execute( task.query );
                    this.aDeferreds.push( defferedTask );
                    

                    promises = all( this.aDeferreds );
                    promises.then( lang.hitch( this, this.handlelinkResults ), lang.hitch( this, function ( err ) {
                    console.error( 'query error', err );
                    this.map.hideLoadingImg();
                    this.stopTimeout = true;
                    if ( this.errorType == null ) {
                        var errorMessage;
                        if ( err.message ) {
                            errorMessage = err.message;
                            console.log(errorMessage);
                        } else {
                            errorMessage = err;
                            console.log(errorMessage);
                        }
                    }

                } ) );

handlelinkResults: function(r) {
        //console.log("Check if handle link results function is used");
        var features = [];
        var featuresValue = [];
        var featuresLayersIds = [];
        var featuresCountForFeaturesLayers = 0;
        var featuresCountForDynamicLayers = 0;

        //console.log("Debug what is r:", r);
        array.forEach(r,function(result,j){
            console.log("debug results:", result);
            console.log(result.features);
            var resultfeat = result.features;
            if ( resultfeat && resultfeat.length > 0) {
                array.forEach( resultfeat, function ( feat, j ) {
                    console.log(feat);
                    var value = feat.value + "_" + feat.layerId;
                    var layerNameId = this.featureLayersNameId[ this.layersRequest[ j ] ];
                    feat.attributes.layerName = layerNameId.layerName;
                    feat.attributes.layerId = layerNameId.layerId;
                    feat.urlLayer = this.layersQueryTask[featuresCountForDynamicLayers].url + "/" + layerId;
                    feat.layerInfos = this.layersQueryTask[featuresCountForDynamicLayers].layerInfos;
                    feat.layer = this.layersQueryTask[featuresCountForDynamicLayers];
                    feat.layer = this.layersQueryTask[featuresCountForDynamicLayers];
                    features.push( feat );
                }, this );}
        },this)}
```

I included the screenshots below. The first image is the query that I constructed and logged in console for debugging. The second image is the returned results. I do not see any feature element in the result for my query.

Where did I go wrong?

[image]

[image]

Comment: You placed quotes around the numeric in the WHERE clause. If the field is integer, this is incorrect.

Comment: Hi, Thank you so much for your reply. I tried changing it to "LK_ID_NUM  = 46014" but the issue still persists. You are right the field is LK_ID_NUM ( type: esriFieldTypeInteger , alias: LK_ID_NUM ).

Comment: I think you need to show your JS code. Your response screen shot doesn't look like the output of a featureservice query. It looks like the definition of the service.

Comment: I have updated the post to include my JS code. Appreciate it. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue. It has to do with the layer URL input. The initial url variable was stored as something like this (https://xxx/arcgis/rest/services/xxx/xxxx/MapServer/). This is ok for identify tasks but for query tasks it requires the layer ID (something like this https://xxx/arcgis/rest/services/xxx/xxxx/MapServer/**0**). All i had to do was to include the layer ID and the query returned the feature as expected.